# Java instanceof doesn't work in my case

Tags: java, instanceof

I have the following classes inheritance structure:

```
public class Document {}
public class AuditProgramDocument extends Document {}
public class CaseFilePart {
    private Document document;
    public Document getDocument() {
        return document;
    }
}
public class MyClass {
    public boolean canDeleteDocument(CaseFilePart selectedCFP) {
        ...//somelogic
        if (selectedCFP.getDocument() instanceof AuditProgramDocument) {
            System.out.println("instance");
        }
    }
}
```

In debugger, I clearly see that, `selectedCFP.getDocument()` returns `AuditProgramDocument`. But `If` statement doesn't evaluated.

My test:

```
System.out.println("2.1 " + selectedCFP.getDocument().getClassName());
System.out.println("2.2 " + selectedCFP.getDocument().getClass().getName());
System.out.println("2.3 " + selectedCFP.getDocument().getClass().getCanonicalName());
System.out.println("2.4 " + selectedCFP.getDocument().getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Results in output: 
*2.1 auditProgramDocument*
*2.2 eu.erp.crams.cmg.bom.document.Document*$$_javassist_79_
*2.3 eu.erp.crams.cmg.bom.document.Document*$$_javassist_79_
*2.4 Document*$$_javassist_79_

Comment: *"Java instanceof doesn't work"* Yes, it does.

Comment: Try to print `selectedCFP.getDocument()` before the if. In general: stuff works; if things are broken, then in 99.999999% of time, it is your code.

Comment: Can you post the code where `selectedCFP.document` is instantiated?

Comment: is Document a hibernate entity?

Comment: @Beezy Is `2.1` actually `auditProgramDocument` (lowercase `a`), or is it `AuditProgramDocument` (uppercase `A`)?

Comment: Javassist is used to do some byte code manipulation. What's the super class of eu.erp.crams.cmg.bom.document.Document$$_javassist_79_? Probably not AuditProgramDocument...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, `selectedCFP.getDocument().getClassName()` returned me in console `auditProgramDocument` with lower case, I don't know why. Because I could compare it as String using `AuditProgramDocument.class.getSimpleName()` which returns `AuditProgramDocument` with upper case

Comment: @Beezy It must be a different class then.

Comment: It IS a different class... 
2.2 eu.erp.crams.cmg.bom.document.Document$$_javassist_79_

Comment: The output of `getClassName()` means almost nothing.  It’s not a standard Java method, it’s a method you wrote.  Perhaps you should include the code for that method in your question.  The code for the `toString` method of Document and its subclasses might also be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to be sure we have the following rules:

`AuditProgramDocument` *is* `Document`

`CaseFilePart` *has* `Document`

When we write the code:

```
Document document = new AuditProgramDocument();
if (document instanceof Document) //true
if (document instanceof AuditProgramDocument) //true
```

But, when we write the code:

```
Document document = someVar.getDocument();
if (document instanceof Document) //true
if (document instanceof AuditProgramDocuemtn) //false
```

The last statement is `false` because `Document` *is not* `AuditProgramDocument`. Because the `getDocument()` method always returns us reference to `Document`, not *subtype*

Answer (score 0):

1)-:In side CaseFilePart class you are creating reference variable of Document class not object of document class.

You should return object of Document class not reference.

2)-:AuditProgramDocument class is child class of Document class we can not down cast it.

3)-:that is  why selectedCFP.getDocument() not instanceof AuditProgramDocument

Answer (score 0):

Try this code... (commented out, but included your original tests)

```
public class MyClass {
    public boolean canDeleteDocument(Document doc) {
        return (doc instanceof AuditProgramDocument);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println("2.1 " + selectedCFP.getDocument().getClassName());//DOES NOT COMPILE
        //Not sure about these tests....
        //System.out.println("2.2 " + selectedCFP.getDocument().getClass().getName());
        //System.out.println("2.3 " + selectedCFP.getDocument().getClass().getCanonicalName());
        //System.out.println("2.4 " + selectedCFP.getDocument().getClass().getSimpleName());

        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        CaseFilePart cfp = new CaseFilePart();

        //TEST 1
        cfp.setDocument(new AuditProgramDocument());
        boolean canDelete = mc.canDeleteDocument(cfp.getDocument());
        System.out.println("Can we delete " + cfp.getDocument().getClass() + " " + canDelete);

        //TEST 2
        cfp.setDocument(new SomeOtherDocument());
        canDelete = mc.canDeleteDocument(cfp.getDocument());
        System.out.println("Can we delete " + cfp.getDocument().getClass() + " " + canDelete);
    }

}

//Put all these in the same file to simplify the answer
class Document {}
class AuditProgramDocument extends Document {}
//Created 2nd Document implementation for illustration
class SomeOtherDocument extends Document {}
class CaseFilePart {
    private Document document;
    public Document getDocument() {
        return document;
    }

    public void setDocument(Document document) {
        this.document = document;
    }
}
```